# How to add WS-Security Header in GreenHat Tester?

Tags: wsdl, soapui

Am trying to send a `SOAP SONAR` request using `GreenHat Tester`, but end up with the error below:

```
<faultstring>WSDoAllReceiver: Incoming message does not contain required Security header</faultstring>
```

but the same request gives the correct and expected results in `SOAP UI`.

Can anyone please help me add `WS-Security` Headers in `GreenHat Tester`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the request message and right-click on the text (String) etc... node. Choose **Properties** and then **WS-Security**. **Enable** it and then add the fields you need to add.

You can see how the entire message will look (raw XML) by hitting the **Preview** button in the **WS-Security** tab.